Liquibase doesn't see changelog
I'm getting this error when trying to start my app:
Liquibase failed to start because no changelog could be found at 'classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml'.
Meanwhile I do have the changelog placed in the correct directory "src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml"
What am I missing here?
I tried setting absolute path and eliminating classpath and reading liquibase tutorials, but seems to just work for them. I'm expecting for liquibase to see changelog and configure itself according to it.
Errortrace:
2024-08-26T07:34:20.570Z  WARN 1 --- [Effective_Mobile_Task_Management] [           main] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
2024-08-26T07:34:20.570803317Z  java.base@17.0.12/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
2024-08-26T07:34:20.570807807Z  java.base@17.0.12/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:252)
2024-08-26T07:34:20.570810105Z  java.base@17.0.12/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1674)
2024-08-26T07:34:20.570812471Z  java.base@17.0.12/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1182)
2024-08-26T07:34:20.570814777Z  java.base@17.0.12/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
2024-08-26T07:34:20.570816992Z  java.base@17.0.12/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1062)
2024-08-26T07:34:20.570835077Z  java.base@17.0.12/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1122)
2024-08-26T07:34:20.570837675Z  java.base@17.0.12/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
2024-08-26T07:34:20.570839785Z  java.base@17.0.12/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
2024-08-26T07:34:20.571320088Z 2024-08-26T07:34:20.571Z  WARN 1 --- [Effective_Mobile_Task_Management] [           main] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [HikariPool-1 connection adder] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
2024-08-26T07:34:20.571349296Z  java.base@17.0.12/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
2024-08-26T07:34:20.571353495Z  java.base@17.0.12/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:252)
2024-08-26T07:34:20.571355766Z  java.base@17.0.12/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1674)
2024-08-26T07:34:20.571357866Z  java.base@17.0.12/java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:460)
2024-08-26T07:34:20.571359931Z  java.base@17.0.12/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1061)
2024-08-26T07:34:20.571362154Z  java.base@17.0.12/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1122)
2024-08-26T07:34:20.571364344Z  java.base@17.0.12/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
2024-08-26T07:34:20.571366638Z  java.base@17.0.12/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
2024-08-26T07:34:20.573155386Z 2024-08-26T07:34:20.572Z  WARN 1 --- [Effective_Mobile_Task_Management] [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server
2024-08-26T07:34:20.573388280Z 2024-08-26T07:34:20.573Z  INFO 1 --- [Effective_Mobile_Task_Management] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2024-08-26T07:34:20.579439324Z 2024-08-26T07:34:20.579Z  INFO 1 --- [Effective_Mobile_Task_Management] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2024-08-26T07:34:20.587723583Z 2024-08-26T07:34:20.587Z  INFO 1 --- [Effective_Mobile_Task_Management] [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 
2024-08-26T07:34:20.587770916Z 
2024-08-26T07:34:20.587775814Z Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-08-26T07:34:20.600844679Z 2024-08-26T07:34:20.600Z ERROR 1 --- [Effective_Mobile_Task_Management] [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 
2024-08-26T07:34:20.600873616Z 
2024-08-26T07:34:20.600876612Z ***************************
2024-08-26T07:34:20.600878969Z APPLICATION FAILED TO START
2024-08-26T07:34:20.600881038Z ***************************
2024-08-26T07:34:20.600894839Z 
2024-08-26T07:34:20.600896977Z Description:
2024-08-26T07:34:20.600898879Z 
2024-08-26T07:34:20.600900793Z Liquibase failed to start because no changelog could be found at 'classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml'.
2024-08-26T07:34:20.600903036Z 
2024-08-26T07:34:20.600904832Z Action:
2024-08-26T07:34:20.600906630Z 
2024-08-26T07:34:20.600908672Z Make sure a Liquibase changelog is present at the configured path.
2024-08-26T07:34:20.600910616Z 

My application.properties:
spring.application.name=Effective_Mobile_Task_Management

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml

server.error.include-message=alway

db.changelog-master.yaml:
databaseChangeLog:
  -include:
    file: db/changelog/changelog-1.yaml


check that you really did create 2 folders (as in db/changelog) and not just one folder with . in its name like db.changelog

I double-checked throw Windows explorer, there are 2 folders. It's just the way IntelliJ IDEA shows it

i believe your class path is wrong, try:
classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml

remove the slash after class path

It shows up with the slash in the error message for some reason, but I have it set up correctly in application.properties:
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml

can you then please provide:

error trace
application.properties


Sure, added them to the description

and did you added your changelog-1 to changelog-master?

Yes, I've added its contents to the description

На скрине у Вас папка называется "db.changelog", а в логах выводит classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml. Попробуйте заменить слэш на точку.

Intellij Idea так показывает папки, это именно changelog в db. Вот такой путь, если копировать от repsoitory: src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml

Сейчас заметил, что параметр spring.liquibase.change-log не меняет путь в ошибке, видимо liquibase его на видит почему-то. Хотя по туториалам и авокомплиту Intellij это то что нужно.

А вы точно запускаете скрипт из папки resources?

Я вижу два варианта, заменить путь на абсолютный или заменить путь на относительный, но от папки проекта (src/main...).

Скрипт запускается от файла compose.yaml в корневой папке проекта. Проект строится при помощи gradle, значит classpath указывает на src/main/resources.
Однако liquibase игнорирует параметр spring.liquibase.change-log в application.properties (хотя вроде и дефолтный путь правильный).
